# Remote mainframe session from Linux

Tags: linux, mainframe

I have a Fedora 14 desktop which I'm trying to use to connect to a client's mainframe (running z/OS). There's a popular 3270 terminal emulator for [Windows](http://www.microfocus.com/products/rumba/), but I haven't been able to find one suitable for Linux.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: What kind of terminal do you want to emulate, and what features do you need? There must be at least a dozen Linux VT100/220 emulators out there, and googling "3270 linux emulator" turned up several.

Comment: I guess I should have been more specific. I was looking for a 3270 emulator

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are looking to emulate 3270 then there is no dearth of choices.

1. You can use Wine and Quick3270 emulator. I have tried this and its just awesome.
2. Linux based:
   a. x3270: http://x3270.bgp.nu/index.html  - Tried it. Its decent and FREE (free as in Freedom)
   b. Jagacy 3270: http://www.jagacy.com/downloads.html (Haven't tried it, but it was used by my colleagues. Its really good.)

**My love - Quick3270 running over Wine.**

Comment: Thanks Nitin! I gave Jagacy a try and it seems to fit what I've been looking for :)

Comment: Craig. Great to know that. Do let me know if you need more help. If you ever plan to automate Quick3270 or IBM MF Communicator automation with Excel to do daily tasks automatically just let me know. I just love it when people automate the day-to-day activities.